# AlertDialog Builder throws an error

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

The `logcat` complains about something with the `alertDialog.show()`. when i comment out the below posted method, the app works, otherwise, it crashes. Please let me know where the error is.

**Java Code:**

```
private void takePictureOrDoNot() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        mAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Picture For Your Location.");
        mAlertDialogBuilder
             .setMessage("Do You Want To Take a Picture Of Your Location?")
             .setCancelable(true)
             .setPositiveButton("YES", mDialogAlertPositiveButtonSetListener)
             .setNegativeButton("NO", mDialogAlertNegativeButtonSetListener);
        AlertDialog mAlertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create(); 
        mAlertDialog.show(); 
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463): 
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is  
not for an application
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:802)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at  
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at 
android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at  
com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.AddNewLocationActivity$3.takePictureOrDoNot(AddNewLocationActivity.java:185)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.AddNewLocationActivity$3.onKey(AddNewLocationActivity.java:150)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7672)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1485)
05-13 22:05:32.766: E/AndroidRuntime(26463):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2293)
```

Comment: In your alert dialog builder, pass in ActivityName.this to the constructor rather than getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

And Read Commonsware answer @

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Comment: @user3558352 google or search on stackvoerflow with  **Unable to add window -- token null is  
not for an application** and you find many similar posts and to know when to use what look at the post i linked to in my post

Answer (score 0):

In an Activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

In a Fragment

```
AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```